# Improper integrals ; Why does this equality hold?

Tags: integration, summation, improper-integrals

$
H(t):=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}-t & (0<t<1) \\
0 & (t=0) \\
\text{periodic of period 1} &(\text{otherwise})
\end{cases}$

$
\mu (x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}-t}{t+x+n} dt.$

My mathematic book says

\begin{align}
\mu (x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}-t}{t+x+n} dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{H(t)}{t+x+n} dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_n^{n+1} \dfrac{H(t)}{t+x} dt \\
&=\lim_{m \to \infty} \displaystyle\int_0^{m}\dfrac{H(t)}{t+x} dt .
\end{align}

But I wonder if
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}-t}{t+x+n} dt
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{H(t)}{t+x+n} dt 
$
holds, because

$H(t)$ is not equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}-t$ at the point of $t=0$ and $t=1.$

So I think I should write

\begin{align}
\mu (x) 
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}-t}{t+x+n} dt\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim_{\epsilon \to +0, \delta \to +0}\displaystyle\int_{\delta}^{1-\epsilon} \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}-t}{t+x+n} dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim_{\epsilon \to +0, \delta \to +0}\displaystyle\int_{\delta}^{1-\epsilon} \dfrac{H(t)}{t+x+n} dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim_{\epsilon \to +0, \delta \to +0}\displaystyle\int_{\delta +n}^{1-\epsilon +n} \dfrac{H(t-n)}{t+x} dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim_{\epsilon \to +0, \delta \to +0}\displaystyle\int_{\delta +n}^{1-\epsilon +n} \dfrac{H(t )}{t+x} dt \\
&=\lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{m} \lim_{\epsilon \to +0, \delta \to +0}\displaystyle\int_{\delta +n}^{1-\epsilon +n} \dfrac{H(t )}{t+x} dt .\\
\end{align}

I caannot show that this is equal to
$\lim_{m \to \infty} \displaystyle\int_0^{m}\dfrac{H(t)}{t+x} dt .$

How should I do? I would like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: The nth terms in the two sums are equal, i.e. the differences $=0$.  A countably infinite sum of zeroes $=0$..

Comment: The value of an integral does not change if you change  the values at a  finite number of points.